# Number of Automorphisms of a Irregular Graph.

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I have been looking for results on  **number of graph automorphisms  of irregular graph**(upper and lower bound).

[I searched](http://www.designtheory.org/library/preprints/auts.pdf) , but could not find anything which can be used directly.

Say, $G$ is $k$ connected irregular graph.
$F_k , f_k $ is the  number of graph automorphisms  of irregular graph $G$, where $n=|G|=$total number of vertices of $G$.

What is the upper bound $f_k(n)$and lower bound $F_k(n)$?

Comment: @MorganRodgers , Highly Irregular Graph  is included , could be other irregular graphs also(simply a graph that is not regular) , let me define: An  irregular graph $G$   that can be divided into total  $ b$ sets of vertices where 1. each set has vertices of same degree 2 . each set create a regular graph(subgraph of given graph). In the question , $b=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT] : the following solution applies to highly irregular graphs (sometimes known as irregular graphs) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_irregular_graph

I'd be surprised if you could find a nice lower bound.  Testing for the irregular graphs on 12 vertices (110 graphs according to Brendan McKay https://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphs.html), most have automorphism group of order 1 or 2 (a single example admits a group of order 4).  All 474 examples on 13 vertices have a trivial automorphism group.

As for an upper bound, you should convince yourself that an automorphism of an (connected) irregular graph that fixes even one vertex must in fact fix the entire graph (why?).  You can consider the number of permutations on $n$ elements that do not fix anything.  But this isn't quite enough, because you need to whole GROUP (all nonidentity elements) to not fix anything! Such a group is said to act semiregularly.

EDIT: After more thinking, since the automorphism group $G$ acts semiregularly, all orbits have size $|G|$.  So $|G|$ divides $n$.  But $G$ can't equal $n$ because that would imply that there is an automorphism sending vertex $a$ to vertex $b$ for all vertex pairs; and we have to send a vertex with degree $d$ to another with degree $d$.  So let $c$ be the number of distinct degrees.  This gives a bound $|G| \leq n/c$.  For example, the special graph on 12 vertices has precisely 4 vertices of degree 1, 4 vertices of degree 2, and 4 vertices of degree 3, arranged perfectly so that there is an automorphism of order 4 = 12/3.

Comment: A class of  irregular graph $G_{\alpha}$, where each graph of  $G_{\alpha}$, say , $G$ , can be divided into total b sets of vertices where 1. each set has vertices of same degree 2 . each set create a regular graph(subgraph of given graph). your bound works on these $G_{\alpha}$ class, right?

Comment: not exactly , set are divided according to  distinct degrees, each set has vertices which are connected otherwise regular graph is not possible, each vertex added to each vertex of $K_5$, means 1 set has 5 vertices of degree 6 and another has 5 vertices of degree 1. These 5 vertices of degree 1 can not make a regular graph, right?